# App Requests Dialog - No Images

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use the FB.ui requests dialog but I was wondering how to display images of the friends instead of just dropping them down as a list.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

If you go to the example 'apprequests' and select "Send To Many" it will just give you a list with a bunch of checkboxes. I believe it is supposed to look full with pictures and all? I tried multiple browsers and another computer and it still doesn't show it. Is is supposed to show just a dropdown list? If so, how can I make it display images? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is very strange that you dont'see the pictures, because using

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```

you should see the names and pictures of your friend.

Answer (score 0):

when i am using my app i can see pictures next to names in the requests dialog, 
but today i saw a friend using it and noticed that when he invited friends his dialog was just a plain list.

I dont think there is any problems with your code , try and ask someone to test and see if they can see pictures or just a plain list.